# Getting extra empty user input while scanning

Tags: kotlin

I'm kinda of new to Kotlin programming.
I have been trying to scan the user input and calculate the fibonacci series for this input.
The problem that I'm facing: I have to enter either a `Enter` Button or any extra text before entering the real scanner value that should calculate the result.

here's the code snippet:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

fun main() {
    val scanner  = Scanner(System.`in`);
    print("Geben Sie bitte eine Zahl ein :");
    calculateFibonacciSequence(scanner.nextLong()).forEach { element->print("${element}\n") };
}
fun calculateFibonacciSequence(n : Long) : Array<Long>{
    val tempArr = mutableListOf<Long>();
    var term1 = 0;
    var term2 = 1;
    var count = 1;

    while (count <= n){

        tempArr.add(term1.toLong());
        val s = term1+term2;
        term1 = term2;
        term2 = s;
        count++;
    }
    val list: Array<Long> = tempArr.toTypedArray();
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Works for me without any additional symbols before input number.
However, it will be more convenient if you use [`println`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/println.html) instead of [`print`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/print.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `readLine()`. It worked for me:

```kotlin
val n = readLine()?.toLongOrNull() ?: error("Please enter a long number")

calculateFibonacciSequence(n)
```

`toLongOrNull()` will try to parse the String as Long, it will return `null` if the String does not represent any Long number.

`?.` are the [safe calls](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#safe-calls)

And `?:` is the [Elvis operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#elvis-operator)